# How to manage more than one git repository in VS Code

Tags: git, repository, visual-studio-code

I have to work with a directory like this:

```
ProjectRoot
|---- SubDirectory1
|---- SubDirectory2(Git Repository1)
|---- SubDirectory3(Git Repository2)
|---- ...
|---- Files
```

But I found that the embedded git function of VS-code does not automatically recognize those sub-directories managed by git.

How to solve this problem? Is there a extension about it?

Comment: It is an open issue https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7829

Comment: @brand-shaw Is ProjectRoot a plain old directory, or is it also a Git repo?

Comment: @wgj It'a a plain directory. Different parts of the project have their own git repo.  Things will be easy If VS code can open more than one folder and can search symbols across different folders.

Answer (score 19):

You can use [multi-root workspaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces). Rather than opening the root directory of your project you can open the first separate git repo then add others using File->Add Folder to Workspace. Once you've added them all you can do File->Save Workspace As to save your new workspace configuration.

Answer (score 13):

As of [version 1.20 of VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_20) (Jan 2018), VS Code has had the setting `git.autoRepositoryDetection`, which allows VS Code automatically detect git repositories. As of this response (2022), the valid settings are:

1. `true`
2. `false`
3. `"subFolders"`
4. `"openEditors"`

The default is `true`, and it will look for git repos in the folder above and in subfolders.  The `"subFolders"` setting limits the search to subfolders only.  And, the `"openEditors"` setting will limit the search to repos open in any open VS Code editor.

With these options in mind, I would reccomend adding an entry to your root workspace's settings.json file.  This can be found in <workspace_root>/.vscode/settings.json, where you will be able to add `"git.autoRepositoryDetection": "subFolders"`.  You can also do this using the "Workspace" set of settings, or for all "User" settings of your VS Code through the settings editor found from "File -> Preferences -> Settings" and searching for the "git.autoRepositoryDetection" setting and then choosing whether you want to set it for all of your VS Code workspaces or just the workspace you're working, via the "User" and "Workspace" tabs at the top.  (see picture)
[image: Setting git.autoRepositoryDetection for the Workspace]

Comment: I was looking for a button or command to "add"/"open"/"detect"/"track" mutliple repositories... VSCode should make this more obvious!

Comment: Seems like exactly the answer. The only problem is that I don't see any git repos in git browser, even after having manually added the subfolders with git projects.

Comment: Same issue, only 3 out of 9 repos are showing in the Source Control pane even after `git.autoRepositoryDetection` = `true` and `git.repositoryScanMaxDepth` set to more than I need

Comment: I had success with restarting VS Code after setting `git.autoRepositoryDetection` to `subFolders` and `git.repositoryScanMaxDepth` to `-1`.  Also seemed good to set `gitlens.advanced.repositorySearchDepth` at the same time

Comment: gitlens is not an out of the box thing, so I ignored it in the response.  It appears from that setting alone that it does its own thing for working with repos anyway.

Answer (score 7):

Version 1.72 (September 2022) has this in the release notes:

> **Source Control**
>
> [Discover nested Git repositories](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_72#_discover-nested-git-repositories)
>
> To address a long standing feature request, this milestone we made
> changes to repository discovery to add support for nested Git
> repositories. Depending on the location of the nested repositories,
> you may need to modify the `git.repositoryScanMaxDepth` setting (the
> default is 1 level).

Answer (score 3):

As already said by wgj, VScode assumes that GIT repo is in same directory level as workspace root. Although there is no way to change this currently, one potentially helpful workaround is to use the project manager extension which makes it easy to open VScode windows to different git repos and to switch between them with a few keystrokes. It is also part of the Git extension pack by Don Jayamanne.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem:

```
- root project (git repo)
  |- subproject 1 (git repo)
  |- subproject 2 (git repo)
```

I wanna handle all three repos in VSCode.

Open `subproject 1` regularly
then "add subfolder to workspace" select `subproject 2`
then "add subfolder to workspace" select `root project`

voilà: you can manage all three repos in one Workspace now

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that ProjectRoot is a not also a git repo (in which you should follow the issue from @hjpotter92's comment, and use the normal `git` command for now)...

VS Code is expecting your git repo (the directory with the `.git` folder) to be your "ProjectRoot" instead. This kind of implies that directories like "SubDirectory1" and "SubDirectory2", while in the same parent, aren't actually part of the same project, and won't be actively worked on together.

Comment: Thank for answering. I use git bash for now, but it's better if vs code can automatically detect .git folder in every directories.